# How to sync/upload lossless music to iOS/iPod devices using Ubuntu?

Tags: sync, music, ipod

It's cool that it's easy to sync Ogg/Mp3/AAC music to the iPod/iPhone/iPad using Rhytmbox or Banshee, but I'm wondering that is it possible to upload lossless music somehow? As far as I know, none of the software above support Apple Lossless format - they can't even play it. Since Apple Lossless is released under the Apache License, I think there must be some open-source solution for Apple Lossless conversion.

Answer (score 0):

They can play it and should support it. However, I think there is a bug in the latest rhythmbox: [Rhythmbox transcoding ALAC files on the fly when syncing ipod (and I don't want it to!)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330188/rhythmbox-transcoding-alac-files-on-the-fly-when-syncing-ipod-and-i-dont-want)

You can also use Clementine to do the job. No sync capabilities, but you can add the music manually with rhythmbox. (and I can confirm it works with apple lossless, as this is the reason I'm using it over rhythmbox at this moment)