# Rhythmbox transcoding ALAC files on the fly when syncing ipod (and I don't want it to!)

Tags: 13.04, rhythmbox, ipod

I use Rhythmbox from the gnome3 ppa (not the one from the main repository because of this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1132215)) on Ubuntu 13.04 and I have an iPod nano 4th gen.

Almost my entire music library is in ALAC (Apple lossless audio codec), which can be played on an iPod. On 12.04 I was able to sync my iPod without problems with Rhythmbox. Now I can sync my iPod, but I discovered that the music gets converted on the fly to some lossy format (I presume AAC?).

I tried to create an .is_audio_player file on the iPod, containing the line `output_formats=audio/mp4, audio/mpeg`. But I didn't expect it to solve a lot, as aac and alac are both withing the mp4 container.

How could I stop rhythmbox from converting my alac files when I sync my iPod?
(or should I file a bugreport?)